# "cannot be resolved to a variable" in for loop

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I am trying to find the factorial of a number using `Scanner`. I am getting an error at `p` as `p` cannot be  resolved to a variable. What does it mean?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fact {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner object = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter a number:\n");
        int i = object.nextInt();

        int result = 1;

        for (p = 1; p <= i; p++) {
            result = result * 1;
            System.out.println("factorial of a number is:result");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

It means you haven't defined a variable `p` (and yet you try to initialize it to `1` in your `for` loop). Change

```
for(p=1;p<=i;p++)
```

to

```
for(int p=1;p<=i;p++)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should define the variable `p` in your `for` loop like you have defined `i` variable like this:

```
for(int p = 1; p <= i; p++)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have several errors here:

The first (and most important) is that you never define `p`. As the other answers say, define it either beforehand (`int p;`) or in the loop.

The second is that you're not actually calculating the factorial, which is an additional problem. But solve problem 1 first as it is a compiler error.

The third is that you're not actually printing the result. You'd need to do `System.out.println("The result was: " + result)`.

Also, you may not want the print statement to be inside the loop...

Answer (score 0):

This code has lot of compilation errors.  The following is the working code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class ScannerEx {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter a number:\n");
    int number = scanner.nextInt();

    int result = 1;


    for(int p=1; p <=number ;p++)  {
        result= result*p;

    }
    System.out.println("Factorial of a number is " + result);
}
```

}

Comment: Starting a class with a capital letter is not a compilation error, just a convention taboo - you make it sound as if it's the first.